# Wordpress admin-ajax.php bad request 400

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

hello  im doing save for later feature in my website
but i get admin-ajax bad request when i click the button

functions.php

```
function zumra_scripts() { wp_register_script( 'remove-prodduct-from-list', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/remove-product.js', array('jquery'), false, true );     wp_localize_script( 'remove-prodduct-from-list', 'sfl_ajax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )) );
    if ( is_page('savelist') ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'remove-prodduct-from-list' );
    }

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'zumra_scripts' );
```

save-for-later.php

```
  <?php

add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action' );

function my_action() {
    $user =         $_POST['user'];
    $post_id =      $_POST['post_id'];
    $response =     $_POST['saveForLater'];
    $response .= '<a href="'. site_url("/savelist") .'">'. __( 'Browse Savelist', 'zumra' ) .'</a>';

    add_user_meta( $user, 'product_id', $post_id);

    echo $response;

    wp_die(); // this is required to terminate immediately and return a proper response
}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_remove_product_from_list', 'remove_product_from_list' );
function remove_product_from_list() {
    $user =     intval( $_POST['user'] );
    $product =  intval( $_POST['product'] );

    delete_user_meta( $user, 'product_id', $product);

    wp_die(); // this is required to terminate immediately and return a proper response
}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_move_to_cart', 'move_to_cart' );
function move_to_cart() {
    $user =     intval( $_POST['user'] );
    $product =  intval( $_POST['product'] );

    delete_user_meta( $user, 'product_id', $product);

    // do_action( 'woocommerce_ajax_added_to_cart', $product );
    // wc_add_to_cart_message( $product );

    wp_die(); // this is required to terminate immediately and return a proper response
}
```

save-for-later.js

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.ajax-form').on('submit',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var data = {
            'action': 'my_action',
            'saveForLater': sfl_ajax.response,
            'user':         sfl_ajax.user,
            'post_id':      sfl_ajax.post_id,
            'product_id':   sfl_ajax.user_product,
        };

        // since 2.8 ajaxurl is always defined in the admin header and points to admin-ajax.php
        jQuery.post(sfl_ajax.ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
            $('.save-for-later').html(response);
        });
    });
});
```

i don't know what im doing wrong 
i get error admin-ajax.php 400 every time i click add to save for later button

Comment: Is that all of your code? If so, then you're missing the part that handles the AJAX request on the PHP side. That's why you're getting the 400 Bad Request error.

Comment: thank you i forgot the php file 
edited the post any help

Comment: The code you have on `save-for-later.php` should be in `functions.php` instead (unless you're including this file in your `functions.php` file)

Comment: it's included in functions.php file

Answer (score 2):

Try to use this codes in your php file:

```
function zumra_scripts() {
          wp_register_script( 'remove-prodduct-from-list', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/remove-product.js', array('jquery'), false, true );

          wp_localize_script( 'remove-prodduct-from-list', 'sfl_ajax', array(
            'ajaxurl'         => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
            'user'.           => get_current_user_id(),
            'post_id'         => get_the_ID(),
            'user_product'    => get_the_ID(), // custom function if any
            'response'        => your_custom_function(), // if any
          );

          if ( is_page( 'savelist' ) ) {
             wp_enqueue_script('remove-prodduct-from-list');
          }
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'zumra_scripts' );
```

Comment: i tried it it didn't work i pasted the code in functions.php

Comment: What is your saveForlater function?

Comment: function my_action()

Answer (score 0):

Solved it was a plugin called WPAML causing this conflict
Thanks Everyone